# how to integrate a function on a n-dim domain

Tags: calculus, integration

how do I solve the following integral?
$$\int_dCXdX$$
when $X=(x_1,x_2,...x_n), C=(c_1,...c_n)$ and D is the domain D={$\beta_i\ge x_i\ge \alpha_i$}

I belive it's including the use of $\sum$ and $\prod$ but I don't know how to write that down...

Comment: You're integrating a linear function (I hope; your notation is not very clear) over a centrally symmetric domain, so the integral is the volume of the domain times the value of the function at the center of the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
  \int_D \langle c,x\rangle \, dx 
  &= \int_D \sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i\, dx\\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_D c_i x_i\, dx\\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\prod_{j} [\alpha_j,\beta_j]} c_i x_i\, dx\\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\ne i} (\beta_j - \alpha_j) c_i \int_{\alpha_i}^{\beta_i} x_i\, dx_i \quad \text{Note that the integrand depends only on $x_i$} \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j\ne i} (\beta_j - \alpha_j) c_i \cdot \left(\frac{\beta_i^2}2 - \frac{\alpha_i^2}2\right)\\
  &= \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n (\beta_j - \alpha_j) c_i \cdot (\alpha_i + \beta_i) \quad \text{We used $\beta^2 - \alpha^2 = (\beta - \alpha)(\beta + \alpha)$}\\
  &= \frac 12 \prod_{j=1}^n (\beta_j - \alpha_j) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n c_i(\alpha_i + \beta_i).
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh ... I lost my $\frac 12$ ... will correct.